# How to manually execute 'restore' on a C# function project in visual studio code?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

In Visual Studio Code my Azure Function project periodically displays a popup asking me to 'restore' the project. It seems to update the libraries and/or connect them to my code. If I click the button restore usually functions to fix the errors.

One of my projects suggests performing a restore, however no popup. How do I manually trigger a restore?

Comment: You're talking about restoring nuget packages with the `dotnet` cli tool? `dotnet restore`? Are you opening this project in both VS and VS Code?

Comment: Yes. Only opening in VS Code for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dotnet restore`.
Here's [microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore).

What this command does is to restore any dependencies: nuget packages, project references and tools for your project/solution, based upon your configuration and current directory (running in a directory with a .sln will restore anything referenced in the solution for example)

It's a prerequisite for all other compilation-related commands, such as `build`, `test` or `publish`.

Usually an IDE like Visual Studio will perform this in the background.
A VSCode extension on the other hand, depending on your settings, might always ask before.